# Can i have multiple site.master files in asp.net - WebForms

Tags: asp.net

I need to create a site that is duplicate to the mail site but in a sub-folder. The subsite will have a slightly different header.

Wondering if it is possible to have 2 seperate site.master files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One ASPX page can have only one Master page.

However, you can inherit a Master page from a Master page.

### ASPX

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/SubMaster.master" ... %>
```

### Sub Master

```
<%@ Master MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Root.master" 
    Codebehind="SubMaster.master.cs" ...  %>
```

### Root Master

```
<%@ Master CodeBehind="Root.master.cs" %>
```